# UIView - UIScrollView odd behaviour

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` named `MenuViewController` in which i create an `UIView` `MessageView` and pass it a `NSString`:

> ```
> MessageView *mess = [[MessageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
> [mess messageString:@"A:text\nM:text\nA:text\nM:text"];
> [self.view addSubview:mess];
> ```

In `MessageView` i am creating an `UIScrollView` and several `UILabels`; my problem is the following and i can't understand the behaviour:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(540, 50, 360, 160)];
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self addSubview:scrollView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)messageString:(NSString *)string
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height/6)];

   >>>>> HERE is the problem <<<<<<

    if i try to add label to scrollView it does not appear
    [scrollView addSubview:label];

    if i try to add label to self it appears
    [self addSubview:label];
}
```

I would like to create all of the content i would like to show here in MessageView and just call it from the view controller. Does anybody have an idea of what may be the problem ?

Comment: When you set the frame of a view it should be in superview's coordinate system. So if you add the label as a subview of the scroll view the label init method should use scrollView.bounds, not scrollView.frame in label's frame calculations. One more note: it would be better to rename messageString to setMessageString  because former style is used for getters, not setters.

Comment: Can you see your scrollview. I see in your question that the x position of the scrollview is 540

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
UIImageView *label = [UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height/6)];
```

Should be producing an error and a warning. For one, you're missing a starting bracket `[`, and on top of that, you're creating a pointer to a UIImageView object, and then assigning a label to it. Try again with the line written out like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height/6)];
```

This is of course assuming that the method is even being called, and the scroll view is non-nil and has a proper frame when you try to access it.

Comment: It was my mistake, i deleted a big part of code from messageString so it was easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the label outside of scrollview's visible frame: Replace

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height/6)];
```

with

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height/6)];
```